# can i write a loop inside a function that has if then else if conditions?

Tags: oracle, plsql

content :  i am writing a function to return a value based on 3 conditions, but i need to write a loop inside it so it can check the conditions for each id passed. can i write that?

code:

```
return varchar2
is
a_hldd_code varchar2();
o_result  varchar2();

cursor c_get_hold_codes is 

Select sprhold_hldd_code,sprhold_pidm,stvhldd_desc
from sprhold 
join stvhldd on stvlhdd_pidm=sprhold_pidm
and sprhold_hldd_code like'T%';

Begin 
open c_get_hold_codes;
fetch c_get_hold_codes into a_hldd_code;
close c_get_hold_codes;

if a_hldd_code in ('TL','TY'..) then
o_result := 'Level 1';

else if a_hldd_code not in () then
0_result := 'Level2';

elseif a_hldd_code is null then
o_result :='Level 3';

End if;
return o_result;
end;
```

---

**[EDIT]**

The function should return level 1 if it falls in the first condition after it reads all the records. eg. an id has 5 records like (TL,T8,T6,T5,T4) it should return only level 1 and not level 2 ... but my function return level 2.. what am i missing?

```
create or replace FUNCTION          fwt_get_holds(
    i_id  id.table_im%TYPE
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    o_level       VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN 
o_level := null;
FOR c IN ( SELECT DISTINCT sprhold_hldd_code
                                               FROM
                                                   sprhold,
                                                   stvhldd
                                               WHERE
                                                   stvhldd_code = sprhold_hldd_code
                                                   AND sprhold_hldd_code LIKE 'T%'
                                                   AND sprhold_to_date >= to_date(sysdate)
                                                   AND sprhold_pidm = i_id)

 LOOP
    IF c.sprhold_hldd_code in ('TF','TB','TY','TL','TS')
    then
    o_level:='Level 1';
    ELSE IF c.sprhold_hldd_code not in ('TF','TB','TY','TL','TS')
    then
    o_level:='Level 2';
    ELSE 
        o_level := 'Level 3';
    END IF;
    RETURN o_level;
END LOOP;


END fwt_get_holds;
```

Comment: Yes you can. What isn't working exactly?

Comment: i am not sure.. how to add the loop in here.. if it is needed to get levels on all ids or the above will return the levels for all ids?

Comment: Perhaps sample data and expected results would help to explain the issue, as it’s still not clear what you need a loop for or why you can’t write one.

Comment: *"check the conditions for each id passed."* What IDs? How are they passed?

Comment: IDS are "for every record in the table the condition should be checked for '

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, nothing of what you want will happen. Bad news, eh?

Code you wrote is wrong - not because of obvious mistakes, but - cursor's `SELECT` statement contains 3 columns which you're fetching into a 1 `varchar2` variable. 3 can't fit into 1; not that way, that is.

---

Moreover, what would you do with a loop *within* the function? It can be done, of course, for example (switching to cursor `FOR` loop for simplicity), but - depending on where you put `RETURN`, you'll either return the first `O_RESULT` value or the last (see comments within the code):

```
for cur_r in (select sprhold_hldd_code, ...
              from sprhold ...
              where --> ID condition missing here; ID you're passing, allegedly
             )
loop
  if cur_r.sprhold_hldd_code in ('TL', 'TY', ...) then ...
     -- in a number of IFs, you find what O_RESULT variable is
  end if;

  -- if you put RETURN here, only one loop iteration will execute

end loop;

-- if you put RETURN here, only the last O_RESULT value will be returned
```

---

It means that you'd actually want to put a loop OUTSIDE of the function, i.e. call the function in a loop for all those `ID`s you're about to pass to the function. Something like this:

```
function f_result (par_id in number) return varchar2 is
  o_result varchar2(20);
begin
  select sprhold_hldd_code
    into l_sprhold_hldd_code
    from sprhold ...
    where some_id = par_id;

  if l_sprhold_hldd_code in ...
     -- find O_RESULT in a number of IFs
  end if;

  return o_result;
end;
```

Now call it in a loop

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select id from some_table where some_condition) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('For ID = ' || cur_r.id || ', function returned ' || f_result(cur_r.id));
  end loop;
end;
```

---

If none of above helps, try to rephrase the question.

Comment: Ive re written like this

Comment: the below function that i wrote does not read each rows...For eg..I have an id that has TL and TY as well as other codes... I expect it to return level 1 for TL and TY and level 2 for the rest. but the function below return the last return level 2.I totally get what you are mentioning here. But is there a way to return for every record ?

Comment: Read what I already said. Try to understand it. You put RETURN into the loop, so it exits the loop at its first turn and never moves on to the second iteration.

Comment: I am not sure if i am unclear or not.. but thank you i am trying to work it out from my end

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for us to reverse engineer business logic from broken code. It is easier to understand clearly stated rules. So this is my interpretation of what you want:

For a given id:

1. return `level 1` if it has distinct codes matching only `('TF','TB','TY','TL','TS')`
2. return `level 2` if it has other codes not matching `('TF','TB','TY','TL','TS')`
3. return `level 3` if it has null codes
4. else return `level 4` (e.g. when NO_DATA_FOUND)

```
create or replace FUNCTION          fwt_get_holds(
    i_id  id.table_im%TYPE
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    l_level1 number := 0;
    l_level2 number := 0;
    l_level3 number := 0;
    l_level4 number := 0;
BEGIN 
  begin
    SELECT count(case when sprhold_hldd_code in ('TF','TB','TY','TL','TS') then 1 end ) as lvl_1
           , count(case when sprhold_hldd_code LIKE 'T%' and sprhold_hldd_code not in ('TF','TB','TY','TL','TS') then 1 end ) as lvl_2
           , count(case when sprhold_hldd_code is null then 1 end ) as lvl_3
    into l_level1
         , l_level2
         , l_level3
      FROM sprhold,
           stvhldd
      WHERE stvhldd_code = sprhold_hldd_code
      AND sprhold_to_date >= trunc(sysdate)
      AND sprhold_pidm = i_id;
    exception
      when others then 
        l_level4 := 1;
   end;
   if l_level4 != 0 then 
      return 'level 4';  -- no data found ?
   elsif l_level3 != 0 then 
      return 'level 3';  -- found some nulls
   elsif l_level2 != 0 then 
      return 'level 2';  -- found some non-matching codes
   else
     return 'level 1';   -- found only matching codes
  end if; 
END fwt_get_holds;
```

---

Quite possibly this is not what you want. If so, I suggest you edit your question to explain your business rules, as I did at the top of this answer.

Comment: yes.. my question alligns with your response.. thanks for your input..

Comment: @arsha So is this the answer? What does looping have to do with it?

Comment: @william .. i was asking for suggestions... i thought only a loop would help me solve my requirements..

Comment: @arsha - if you found this solution helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the value of this site for other Seekers.